# How do I connect StaticListableBeanFactory with ClassPathXmlApplicationContext?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, junit

In the setup of my test cases, I have this code:

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "spring/common.xml"
    );
    StaticListableBeanFactory testBeanFactory = new StaticListableBeanFactory();
```

How do I connect the two in such a way that tests can register beans in the `testBeanFactory` during setup and the rest of the application uses them instead of the ones defined in `common.xml`?

Note: I need to mix a static (common.xml) and a dynamic configuration. I can't use XML for the latter because that would mean to write > 1000 XML files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.registerSingleton()` instead of `StaticListableBeanFactory.addBean()`:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "spring/common.xml" 
    ); 

GenericApplicationContext child = new GenericApplicationContext(context);

child.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("foo", ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative you might like to try is to have a Test.xml with the bean definitions that imports your common.xml:

```
<import resource="spring/common.xml"/>

<bean id="AnIdThatOverridesSomethingInCommon"/>
```

You can only have one bean definition with a particular id - in the same file it's an XML validation error, in different files Spring will override the definition.

Edit: Just noticed that this is not suitable for your case - I'll leave it here for completeness.

Comment: Thanks - this is actually what I use but I guess you wouldn't want to if you're trying to apply this to a load of existing tests.